# Split 5 or 6 character string in DataFrame into two 3-2 or 3-3 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a column that I would like to split into two new columns… the first column is 5 or 6 characters and the resultant columns are 3-3 when the first column is 6 characters and 3-2 when the first column is 5 characters

Here’s an example

12345    123    45

456789   456    789

I have tried .str[3:] and .str[-2:] but this obviously doesn’t know which is the appropriate length

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['12345', '456789'])
```

s

```
0     12345
1    456789
dtype: object
```

**Code**

use str.extract

```
s.str.extract(r'(.{3})(.+)')
```

output:

```
    0   1
0   123 45
1   456 789
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
s = "12345"
print(s[:3], s[3:])
```

- `s[:3]` returns the first 3 chars of the string
- `s[3:]` returns the string starting from index of 3

---

`s[-2:]` will always return the last two characters.

---

### Example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["12345", "123456", "abcde"], columns=["Strings"])
df['start'] = df['Strings'].str[:3]
df['end'] = df['Strings'].str[3:]
print(df)
```

*Output:*

```
  Strings start  end
0   12345   123   45
1  123456   123  456
2   abcde   abc   de
```

Comment: You can use this slicing in the .str notation: `df['Col1'].str[:3]` and `df['Col1'].str[3:]`